# I want to print all json object to html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

{

"restaurantId":1,
"name":"food panda",
"dateAddedd":1455647400000,
"lastModified":1455733800000,
"restaurantUrl":"www.foodpanda.com",
"restaurantType":"chinese",
"description":"good and delicious food",
"parking":false,"noOfTable":80,
"noOfwaiter":990,
"wifi":false,

"vendorId":1,
"catalog":[
    {
    "catalogId":1,
    "catalogName":"food",
    "restaurantId":1,
    "vendorId":1,
    "category":[
    {
    "categoryId":1,
    "categoryName":"southindian dosa",
    "catalogId":1,
    "restaurantId":1,
    "vendorId":1,

```
"subCategory":[
{
"subCategoryId":1,
"catalogId":1,
"catCategory_Id":1,
"vendorId":1,
"restaurantId":1,
"subCategoryName":"chapatti",

"product":[
{"productId":2,
"vendorId":2,
"restaurantId":1,
"calalogId":1,
"catCategoryId":2,
"subCategoryId":1,
"taxClassId":12,
"activationDate":1455906600000,
"availability":false,
"discound":12.0,
"hot":true,
"listPrice":120.0,
"longDescription":"Description",
"productName":"Mobile",
"sellingPrice":3000.0,
"weight":20,
"productOption":[
]}]}]}]},
{
"catalogId":2,
"catalogName":"drinks",
"restaurantId":1,
"vendorId":1,
"category":[
{
"categoryId":2,
"categoryName":"Norythindian dosa",
"catalogId":2,
"restaurantId":1,
"vendorId":1,

"subCategory":[
{"subCategoryId":3,
"catalogId":1,
"catCategory_Id":2,
"vendorId":1,
"restaurantId":1,
"subCategoryName":"Paratha",
"product":[]},
{
"subCategoryId":2,
"catalogId":2,
"catCategory_Id":2,
"vendorId":1,
"restaurantId":1,
"subCategoryName":"apple juice",
"product":[
{
"productId":1,
"vendorId":1,
"restaurantId":1,
"calalogId":1,
"catCategoryId":1,
"subCategoryId":2,
"taxClassId":10,
"activationDate":1455733800000,
"availability":true,"discound":0.0,
"hot":true,
"listPrice":10.0,
"longDescription":"onion dosa with butter",
"productName":"oninoin dosa",
"sellingPrice":12.6,
"weight":100,

"productOption":[
{
"productOptionId":1,
"productId":1,
"optionName":"coca cola drinks",
"optionValues":"200",
"comment":"all the dishes are available ",
"price":10.0},
{
"productOptionId":2,
"productId":1,
"optionName":"coca cola drinks",
"optionValues":"500",
"comment":"allncjncjd cndknc mcnmdc",
"price":20.0}
]}
]}
]}
]}
]}
```

Comment: And what did you try before asking the community?

Comment: You should try to explain better and format your question

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
var obj = {
    "restaurantId" : 1,
    "name" : "food panda",
    "dateAddedd" : 1455647400000,
    "lastModified" : 1455733800000,
    "restaurantUrl" : "www.foodpanda.com",
    "restaurantType" : "chinese",
    "description" : "good and delicious food",
    "parking" : false,
    "noOfTable" : 80,
    "noOfwaiter" : 990,
    "wifi" : false,
    "vendorId" : 1,
    "catalog" : [{
            "catalogId" : 1,
            "catalogName" : "food",
            "restaurantId" : 1,
            "vendorId" : 1,
            "category" : [{
                    "categoryId" : 1,
                    "categoryName" : "southindian dosa",
                    "catalogId" : 1,
                    "restaurantId" : 1,
                    "vendorId" : 1,
                    "subCategory" : [{
                            "subCategoryId" : 1,
                            "catalogId" : 1,
                            "catCategory_Id" : 1,
                            "vendorId" : 1,
                            "restaurantId" : 1,
                            "subCategoryName" : "chapatti",
                            "product" : [{
                                    "productId" : 2,
                                    "vendorId" : 2,
                                    "restaurantId" : 1,
                                    "calalogId" : 1,
                                    "catCategoryId" : 2,
                                    "subCategoryId" : 1,
                                    "taxClassId" : 12,
                                    "activationDate" : 1455906600000,
                                    "availability" : false,
                                    "discound" : 12.0,
                                    "hot" : true,
                                    "listPrice" : 120.0,
                                    "longDescription" : "Description",
                                    "productName" : "Mobile",
                                    "sellingPrice" : 3000.0,
                                    "weight" : 20,
                                    "productOption" : [
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "catalogId" : 2,
            "catalogName" : "drinks",
            "restaurantId" : 1,
            "vendorId" : 1,
            "category" : [{
                    "categoryId" : 2,
                    "categoryName" : "Norythindian dosa",
                    "catalogId" : 2,
                    "restaurantId" : 1,
                    "vendorId" : 1,
                    "subCategory" : [{
                            "subCategoryId" : 3,
                            "catalogId" : 1,
                            "catCategory_Id" : 2,
                            "vendorId" : 1,
                            "restaurantId" : 1,
                            "subCategoryName" : "Paratha",
                            "product" : []
                        }, {
                            "subCategoryId" : 2,
                            "catalogId" : 2,
                            "catCategory_Id" : 2,
                            "vendorId" : 1,
                            "restaurantId" : 1,
                            "subCategoryName" : "apple juice",
                            "product" : [{
                                    "productId" : 1,
                                    "vendorId" : 1,
                                    "restaurantId" : 1,
                                    "calalogId" : 1,
                                    "catCategoryId" : 1,
                                    "subCategoryId" : 2,
                                    "taxClassId" : 10,
                                    "activationDate" : 1455733800000,
                                    "availability" : true,
                                    "discound" : 0.0,
                                    "hot" : true,
                                    "listPrice" : 10.0,
                                    "longDescription" : "onion dosa with butter",
                                    "productName" : "oninoin dosa",
                                    "sellingPrice" : 12.6,
                                    "weight" : 100,
                                    "productOption" : [{
                                            "productOptionId" : 1,
                                            "productId" : 1,
                                            "optionName" : "coca cola drinks",
                                            "optionValues" : "200",
                                            "comment" : "all the dishes are available ",
                                            "price" : 10.0
                                        }, {
                                            "productOptionId" : 2,
                                            "productId" : 1,
                                            "optionName" : "coca cola drinks",
                                            "optionValues" : "500",
                                            "comment" : "allncjncjd cndknc mcnmdc",
                                            "price" : 20.0
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj,null,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following can be used

```
var data = {
  "data": {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "1",
    "url": "http://url.com"
  },
  "event": "start",
  "show": 1,
 "id": 50
}


document.getElementById("json").textContent = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
```

with html as

```
<pre id="json"></pre>
```